# How can I used regular expressions to find all lines of source code defining a default arguments for a function?

Tags: regex

I want to find lines of code which declare functions with default arguments, such as:

```
int sum(int a, int b=10, int c=20);
```

I was thinking I would look for:

> 1. The first part of the matched pattern is exactly one left-parenthesis "`(`"
> 2. The second part of string is one or more of any character excluding "`=`"
> 3. exactly one equals-sign "`=`"
> 4. a non-equal-sign
> 5. one or more characters except right parenthesis "`)`"
> 6. "`)`"

The following is my attempt:

```
([^=]+=[^=][^)]+)
```

I would like to avoid matching condition-clauses for if-statements and while-loops.

For example,

```
int x = 5;
if (x = 10) {
    x = 7;
}
```

Our regex should find functions with default arguments in any one of ***python***, ***Java***, or ***C++***. Let us not assume that function declarations end with semi-colon, or begin with a data-type

Comment: Firstly, the parentheses outside the alternation need to be escaped, \( and \), respectively

Comment: Please check [this one](https://regex101.com/r/KdT1kX/1).

Comment: @marianc - It also matches functions without default arguments right ?

Comment: @rootkonda Yes. I added one more test case. Please [check here](https://regex101.com/r/KdT1kX/3)

Comment: Please check this one...\w+\s\w+\([\w\s,]+(?=\={1})[\w\s,=]+?\) it only matches the functions with default arguments. You can try this out in https://regex101.com/

Comment: You can remove java from the list of languages it must work with, because java does not support default parameter values. However groovy, which is not java, but is based on java, does.

Comment: This will be a hard process with regex but check https://regex101.com/r/cvZA1M/2/. It may answer your question

Answer (score 1):

Please check this one:

```
\(((?:\w+\s+[\w][\w\s=]*,*\s*){1,})\)
```

The above expression matches the parameter list and returns it as $1 (Group 1), in case it is needed for further processing.

[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/KdT1kX/3)

Comment: I think that your regex pattern specifically looks for datatype names, such as `int` or `float`. In the question, I explained that the solution must work for python. Python does not have data-types specified in the function declaration/definition

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\([^)]*\w+\s+\w+\s*=[^),][^)]*\)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/HlcuUw48GAkZYX).

It looks for words chars (the param type), space(s), word chars (the param name), optional space(s), then an equals sign.

Add `".*"` to each end to match the whole line.